# debugging in eclipse the link between a java application and a c dll thread

Tags: java, c, eclipse, dll

I have a java application which spins off a c dll thread.  This has worked for years.  Now, I need to add an argument to the interface between java and the c dll.  I added the necessary additional arguments to both the java and c code.  I screwed up because now I get a UnsatisfiedLinkError when the c dll is supposed to be spun off.  I use eclipse development environment.  My question is:  how do I debug this error in eclipse?

Thanks for your consideration.

Currently, I put a break point in the java code where the c dll is spun off. At the break point, I was hoping to be able to interrogate what the java is looking for so I can find out where I made my mistake.  However, the eclipse go straight to UnsatisfiedLinkError with no opportunity that I can see to interrogate what it is looking for.  Is there any available tool, or part of Eclipse that I don't know about that can tell me what the java is looking for?

Comment: Go through it: https://rollbar.com/blog/java-unsatisfiedlinkerror-runtime-error/#

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without you posting some parts of your code, or the full message for the exception, it is practically impossible to deduce where/why it's going wrong.

That said, an ```UnsatisfiedLinkError``` is highly suggestive. You should have an interface class in your code that defines the functions in the C DLL. At runtime, if these mismatch, you will get an UnsatisfiedLinkError. However, you might also get this when the DLL cannot be found to be loaded. In the case of mismatches, it's not just the function names that should match, but the arguments once converted to Java type equivalents.

Comment: In addition to my earlier comment, but in regards to debugging, you mention the application has been around for years, so it is likely you are using JNA to load the DLL and should find ```Native.loadLibrary``` somewhere in your code. Ensure there's a try-catch around it and learn how DLL locations are resolved on your OS. It could be the DLL is not getting resolved. If it is, then you've not correctly defined the additional functions in Java correctly, or you have but are still using an older DLL that doesn't have the implementation.